# Controller Function called twice in exact same time

Tags: magento-1.9

This is very strange. I have a log of my custom controller called. On one occasion the `action` was called twice. The more strange thing is log time is exact same.

> 2019-08-14T05:16:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): makeBooking +++++++++++
>
> 2019-08-14T05:16:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"customerCode":
>
> 2019-08-14T05:16:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): makeBooking +++++++++++
>
> 2019-08-14T05:16:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"customerCode":

I can confirm this action was called by single user.

And the thing is, I cannot reproduce it. It has happened on 1 occasion and system allowed to create a shipment twice for an order.

Now, I have 2 shipments for a single order.

My action code:

```
/**
 * Book Shipment
 */
public function bookShipmentAction()
{
    $orderId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $quoteId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_id');
    $order = $this->_initOrder(); //it's right order object
    $shipment = $this->_initShipment(); //it's right shipment object
    
        if (!$order->canShip()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Order # %s cannot be shipped.', $order->getIncrementId()));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('order_id' => $orderId));
            return;
        }
    
    try {
        $bookingModel = Mage::getModel('my_module/booking');
        $booking = $bookingModel->bookShipment($order);
        //create magneto shipment
        $this->createMangentoOrder($shipment, $order, $booking, true);
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The shipment has been booked.'));
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__("Unable to book shipment for this order. ".$e->getMessage()));
    }
    
    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}

protected function createMangentoOrder($shipment, $order, $booking, $sendMail = false)
{
    if(!$booking->getId()){
        return;
    }
    
    $processedItems = array();
    $qtys = array();
        foreach ($shipment->getAllItems() as $shipmentItem) {
            $shipQty = (int)$shipmentItem->getQty();
            if ($shipQty && !$shipmentItem->getOrderItem()->getIsVirtual()) {
                $qtys[$shipmentItem->getOrderItem()->getId()] = $shipQty;
            }
        }

    $mageShipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($qtys);
    /* @var $mageShipment Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment */

    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track');
    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Track */
    $track
        ->setCarrierCode('my_code')
        ->setTitle('My Title')
        ->setNumber($booking->getTrackingNumber()) //gives you tracking number
        ;
    $mageShipment->addTrack($track)->register();
    $mageShipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true)->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);
    Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($mageShipment)
            ->addObject($mageShipment->getOrder())
            ->save();
    if ($sendMail) {
        $mageShipment->sendEmail()->setEmailSent(true)->save();
    }
}
```

It looks to me the action function called cuncurrently. How is that even possible?

Comment: This is silly but try double click on shipment button or submit button and check if this is reproduced :)

Comment: Sometimes when you double click on submit it sends two request at the same time. This could be the issue

Comment: Thought so and tried already, but cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue but in a C# WebApp MVC5. Everything usually works perfectly, users create invoices every minute, there are 10 users making invoices concurrently in different locations and different machines.
The issue happens once a week. In the logs, I can see the post is called twice at the same time by the same user, I see some network lag on the client-side when this happens, but I'm not able to reproduce it, even using the network utility of chrome DevTools to simulate network lag.
Of course, I can add some business validation before persisting the data into the database in order to avoid duplicate data, but that's not the real issue.
Has anyone solved the issue?